# finding a minimum value with all header values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I am trying to find a minimum value in a dataframe with all column values.

**Sample data:**

```
**Fitness Value MSU Locations   MSU Range** 
1.180694        {17, 38, 15}    2.017782    
1.202132        {10, 22, 39}    2.032507    
1.179097        {10, 5, 38}     2.048932    
1.175793        {27, 20, 36}    1.820395    
1.187460        {33, 10, 34}    1.922506
```

I am trying to find a minimum value in `Fitness Value` column and keeping the whole row record. For intance, If I get the minimum value (`1.175793`), I want to keep its respective header values which are `{27, 20, 36}` and `1.820395`. So, the final **output** should be:

```
1.175793           {27, 20, 36}      1.820395
```

**My sample code:**

```
minValue = df_2['Fitness Value'].min()
print("minimum value in column 'y': " , minValue)
```

**Output:**

```
minimum value in column 'y':  1.175793
```

**I also tried this code:**

```
df_y = pd.DataFrame ()
df_y = df_2.loc[[df_2['Fitness Value']].min()
```

**How can I get an output like this?**

```
1.175793           {27, 20, 36}      1.820395
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.min.html) with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.loc[df['Fitness Value'].eq(df['Fitness Value'].min())]
```

Output:

```
   Fitness Value MSU Locations  MSU Range
3       1.175793  {27, 20, 36}   1.820395
```

*NB. the difference between my answer and that of @jezrael lies in the handling of duplicates in "Fitness Value". Mine keeps all rows with the min, `idxmin` keeps only the first min. To adapt, depending on what you want.*

Comment: Yes. Your solution is also handling duplicates. it was important to be addressed. Thank you.

Comment: @LearningLogic so I'm confused, which one did you need, this one or `idxmin`?

Comment: I am still trying since I am getting duplications. There are similar minimum values in multiple lists after iterations. I need to put only one on my list.

Comment: @LearningLogic - If need only one need `.idxmin`

Comment: @LearningLogic I think your goal is still unclear, why don't you update your example to show what is really expected in the real use case

Comment: @mozway You are right. I might post another question since I am getting duplicates even after using `df.loc[df['Fitness Value'].eq(df['Fitness Value'].min())]`.

Comment: @mozway I tried to better present my work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74548310/how-to-avoid-duplicates-while-looking-for-a-minimum-value

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html) for indices by minimal values, select row by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for get row first minimal value in `Fitness Value` column:

```
df = df_2.loc[[df_2['Fitness Value'].idxmin()]]
print (df)
   Fitness Value MSU Locations  MSU Range
3       1.175793    {27,20,36}   1.820395
```

If need list without columns:

```
L = df_2.loc[df_2['Fitness Value'].idxmin()].tolist()
```

If need loop:

```
out = []
for x in range(0, 2, 1): 
    new_generation = genetic_algorithm(initial_pop_chromosome_fitness)   
    initial_pop_chromosome_fitness = new_generation

    #create Series and append to list of Series out
    s = df_2.loc[df_2['Fitness Value'].idxmin()]
    out.append(L)

df = pd.DataFrame(out)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249849/discussion-on-answer-by-jezrael-finding-a-minimum-value-with-all-header-values).

Comment: Hi @jezrael can you take a quick look at the relevant questions?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74548310/how-to-avoid-duplicates-while-looking-for-a-minimum-value

Answer (score 1):

A solution using your `minValue` variable.

```py
df[df["Fitness Value"]==minValue]
```